# for loop returns no value of GET variables on echo in php

Tags: php, for-loop, concatenation

This is my url:

```
http://example.com/shop-login.php?itemCount=1&item_name_1=+product1&item_quantity_1=1&item_price_1=23.52&item_options_1=color%3A+Color%2C+pid%3A+5&Shipping_Option=EMS-Express
```

The following php command:

```
echo $_GET['item_name_1'];
```

is giving value as product1 correctly.

But the following code produces no output on for loop

```
$i = 1;
for ($i = 1; $i < $item_count; $i++) {
    $item_name_.$i = $_GET["item_name_".$i];
    echo $item_name_.$i .'<br />' ;
    $item_quantity_.$i = $_GET["item_quantity_".$i];
    echo $item_quantity_.$i .'<br />' ;
    $item_price_.$i = $_GET["item_price_".$i];
    echo $item_price_.$i .'<br />' ;
    $item_options_.$i = $_GET["item_options_".$i];
    echo $item_options_.$i .'<br />' ;
}
```

I want to get values like item_name_1, item_name_2 in url using $_GET[] ????

Comment: what is `$item_name_.$i = …` trying to do?

Comment: you cannot write variables like `$item_name_.$i`

Comment: @Valentin Mercier If so how will i get variables in url like: item_name_1, item_name_2 etc using $_GET[] ???

Comment: Consider looking at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When approaching tasks in programming, you should ask yourself what's
the best data-structure for your task. In this case I believe an array is a better
approach.
So consider using a multi-dimensional array `items`.

Also notice that your `loop` condition is `$i < $item_count`
and in your example $item_count will be equals 1 and 1 isn't < than 1.

```
$item_count = (int) $_GET['itemsCount'];
$i = 1;
$items = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= $item_count; $i++) {
    $items[$i]['name'] = $_GET["item_name_".$i];
    echo $items[$i]['name'] .'<br />' ;
    $items[$i]['quantity'] = $_GET["item_quantity_".$i];
    echo $items[$i]['quantity'] .'<br />' ;
    $items[$i]['price'] = $_GET["item_price_".$i];
    echo $items[$i]['price'] .'<br />' ;
    $items[$i]['options'] = $_GET["item_options_".$i];
    echo $items[$i]['options'] .'<br />' ;
}
```

Comment: Please notice that I edited the code and changed the loop condition.

Comment: If you use that approach, you should initialize an array in the first line of the for loop for `$items[$i]`.

Comment: @sjagr , as far as I know you don't need to do it in PHP.

Comment: In this case, if assigning each element individually as opposed through an inititalizer, it might be relevant to use `$items[$i] = array(); $item = &items[$i];` and then use `$item` for the remainder of the loop body to make the code less repetitive.. the initialization of each item [array] is also relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$item_name_.$i`, use `${'item_name_'.$i}`. Read more on [variable variables here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Also check the value of `$item_count`. If it is less than or equal to `1`, the `for` loop will not execute.

Here's the syntax-correct code:

```
$i = 1;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $item_count; $i++) {
    ${'item_name_'.$i} = $_GET["item_name_".$i];
    echo ${'item_name_'.$i} .'<br />' ;
    ${'item_quantity_'.$i} = $_GET["item_quantity_".$i];
    echo ${'item_quantity_'.$i} .'<br />' ;
    ${'item_price_'.$i} = $_GET["item_price_".$i];
    echo ${'item_price_'.$i} .'<br />' ;
    ${'item_options_'.$i} = $_GET["item_options_".$i];
    echo ${'item_options_'.$i} .'<br />' ;
}
```

You may find that using a multi-dimensional array would be easier in the context that you're using

```
$i = 1;
$items = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $item_count; $i++) {
    $items[$i] = array(
        'name' => $_GET['item_name_'.$i],
        'quantity' => $_GET['item_quantity_'.$i],
        'price' => $_GET['item_price_'.$i],
        'options' => $_GET['item_options_'.$i],
    );
    // Outputting statements here
}
```

Comment: Please do not encourage variable variables - the only "correct" code is the second form, IMOHO :>

Comment: @user2864740 I'm not encouraging anything. I wouldn't even encourage the way OP is using GET variables, but I'm addressing the issues with their code and providing the correct syntax to what they're trying to specifically achieve.

Comment: @sjagr Unfortunately getting no output ??? print_r($items); also produces no results ??

Comment: @user3790186 You ignored my warning of your `$item_count` variable. Try my edit and change `$i < $itemcount` to `$i <= $itemcount`

Answer (score 0):

Use an array something like below

```
$arr = array();
for ($i = 1; $i < $item_count; $i++) {
    if(isset($_GET["item_name_".$i]))
        $arr['item_name'][] = $_GET["item_name_".$i];
    if(isset($_GET["item_quantity_".$i]))
        $arr['item_quantity'][] = $_GET["item_quantity_".$i];
    if(isset($_GET["item_options_".$i]))
        $arr['item_options'][] = $_GET["item_options_".$i];
}
print_r($arr);
```